# How to remove table column with CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I have a table that I am trying to make mobile friendly, so when the screen is a certain width I remove an unnecessary column.  Here is the CSS for that:

```
@media (max-width: 640px) 
{
    .urlCell
    {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

The above code does the job of removing the cells with the #urlCell id, but the remaining cells do not fill the table.  Instead their width remains as though there is still another column there, and also the border for the missing cells remain:
[image]

Comment: Can you add the code for your table?

Comment: as @Okomikeruko said, please add enough code to create a [mcve]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the problem.  There is a hidden row between each row that was causing the issue.  Removing that along with the column fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You could apply the same class to the relevant `th`s and `td`s.

See code sample below

```css
th, td {
  width: 20%;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  text-align: center;
}

@media (max-width: 640px) 
{
    .three
    {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th class="one">One</th>
    <th class="two">Two</th>
    <th class="three">Three</th>
    <th class="four">Four</th>
    <th class="five">Five</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="one">1</td>
    <td class="two">2</td>
    <td class="three">3</td>
    <td class="four">4</td>
    <td class="five">5</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please comment if you downvote for me to improve the answer... otherwise, there is nothing I can do about it

Answer (score 0):

Adding a display none class to all the cells you want to hide should work.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th class="urlCell">Last Name</th>
            <th>Username</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td class="urlCell">Otto</td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td class="urlCell">Thornton</td>
            <td>@fat</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td class="urlCell">the Bird</td>
            <td>@twitter</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>


@media (max-width: 640px) 
{
    .urlCell
    {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ccnxa7b6/

Answer (score 0):

tables are by design not meant for hiding specified columns. my advice is to use flex, a css tech made to solve all our problems, really :D